# Date values from json object are not correctly mapped on the x axis of the dc.js line chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

The data which I want to use for my line chart looks something like this:

```
{ "quarters" : [{ "dateName":"Q1 - 2015", "total":45, "date": "01/02/2015", "location": "WW AA", "care": "Care1", "serviceType": "Long Term Care" }, 
{ "dateName":"Q2 - 2015", "total":10, "date": "01/05/2015", "location": "BB AA", "care": "Care2", "serviceType": "Independent Residence" },
{ "dateName":"Q3 - 2015", "total":35, "date": "01/08/2015", "location": "WW AA", "care": "Care1", "serviceType": "Long Term Care" }, 
{ "dateName":"Q4 - 2015", "total":22, "date": "01/11/2015", "location": "GG NN", "care": "Care1 LTC", "serviceType": "Assisted Living" },{ "dateName":"Q1 - 2016", "total":20, "date": "01/02/2016", "location": "GG NN", "care": "Care2", "serviceType": "Private Long Term Care" }, { "dateName":"Q2 - 2016", "total":10, "date": "01/05/2016", "location": "WW AA", "care": "Care3 LTC" , "serviceType": "Independent Residence" }, { "dateName":"Q3 - 2016", "total":11, "date": "01/08/2016", "location": "BB AA",  "care": "Care3", "serviceType": "Assisted Living"  }, { "dateName":"Q4 - 2016", "total":22, "date": "01/11/2016", "location": "BB AA",  "care": "Care3", "serviceType": "Private Long Term Care" }]}"
```

Depending on the use case, I can have days, months or quarters (as in this example) as my date fields. In a perfect scenario, I would have used the dateName fields values as my X axis values (which worked), but I couldn't make the brush work with ordinal values on the X axis.

This is why I decided to use the date fields instead, and format the date displayed on the X axis ticks so it would show the respective dateName.

The problem is that the values generated on the X axis are different from the values I have in my datasource. For example, instead of 1 February 2015(01/02/2015), 5 May 2015 (01/05/2015) the x axis generates April, July, etc. How can I display my own date values on the X axis?

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9z6d2sk/17/)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem so I will post the answer in case anyone will stumble upon the same issue. It is not perfect, but it worked for me.
What I did is use the xAxis().tickValues(valuesArray) to modify the displayed values on the X axis and xAxis().tickFormat() to return the label value that I wanted.

```
tstChart.xAxis().tickValues(datesArray).tickFormat(function (d) { 
    return getDateName(jsonObjArray,d);
});
```

From what I understood by reading the documentation, using xAxis() to modify the axis properties can sometimes create some problems, but it worked fine in my case. [Here is the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/w9z6d2sk/26/)